# Snaps won't launch on fresh 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, snap

I did a fresh install of 16.04.1, installed snapd, and upgraded the OS. I have installed a bunch of snap apps, because well snaps seem very snappy. They are installed, but will not launch. I even tried a restart
I click the icon in the Dash, it shows up in the dock, blinking for a few seconds then disappears. Nothing. I want to use these, but they are not launching.

Ran the below, after trying to launch the Inkscape snap.

```
macdonald@maclaptop:~$ sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog
[sudo] password for macdonald: 
Feb 15 19:43:33 maclaptop snap[23790]: #015#033[KAll snaps up to date.
Feb 15 19:43:33 maclaptop systemd[1]: Started Automatically refresh installed snaps.
Feb 15 19:43:33 maclaptop systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 5h 59min 56.837468s random time.
Feb 15 19:43:33 maclaptop systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 2h 45min 16.238157s random time.
Feb 15 20:17:01 maclaptop CRON[23921]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 15 21:17:02 maclaptop CRON[24158]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 15 22:17:01 maclaptop CRON[24412]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb 15 22:34:47 maclaptop gnome-session[2002]: ** (zeitgeist-datahub:2437): WARNING **: zeitgeist-datahub.vala:212: Error during inserting events: GDBus.Error:org.gnome.zeitgeist.EngineError.InvalidArgument: Incomplete event: interpretation, manifestation and actor are required
Feb 15 22:38:07 maclaptop sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/macdonald is already mounted
Feb 15 22:40:36 maclaptop sudo: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/macdonald is already mounted
```

Comment: Corebird, Inkscape, kgeography, krita, remmina, spotifywebplayer and VLC... All installed, in the dash and will not launch. They won't launch via terminal.

Comment: Your commented above, along with error messages in terminal, should be edited into the question itself. Please do not leave relevant information in comments only.

Comment: Aww geez thanks for the excellent help in finding a solution to my problem CelticWarrior.

Comment: run `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` in a terminal. Try to launch one of the snaps, and let us know what appeared in syslog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is what I did. I removed and --purged snapd. Reinstall snapd, then installed the Inkscape snap... And it launched. However, this came up when I installed Inkscape:

macdonald@maclaptop:~$ sudo snap install inkscape
2017-02-16T19:20:08-06:00 INFO snap "core" has bad plugs or slots: core-support (unknown interface)

inkscape 0.92.1 from 'inkscape' installed
Going to try install a bunch of other snaps now,and it works!

Comment: Fixed it! Aw, Snap!